# Scrapy shell response.xpath returning blank array [ ]

Tags: python, shell, xpath, scrapy

The xpath is:

```
/html/body/form/div[12]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[13]/ul/li[*]/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/div[3]
```

I am getting the output through Chrome Console through the string below:

```
$x('/html/body/form/div[12]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[13]/ul/li[*]/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/div[3]/text()')
```

But when I type response.xpath instead of $s and include .extract() at the end in Scrapy shell, it returns a blank array [].

```
>>> response.xpath('/html/body/form/div[12]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[13]/ul/li[*]/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/div[3]/text()').extract()
```

[]

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance

PS: I know it's an absolute path. Want to understand why it's working in Chrome Console, and not in Scrapy Shell

Comment: You should post the link.

Comment: Hi, My bad... the site link in question is :

http://www.craftsvilla.com/jewellery-jewelry.html

Answer (score 0):

some times body tag doesn't exist in source, but browser add it. so xpath doesn't work using body tag

so maybe you can give a try to

```
/html//form/div[12]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[13]/ul/li[*]/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/div[3]/text()
```

on the other hand your xpath looks like very hard coded, it should be flexible enough .. you should read out a xpath tutorial and make it simple using Elements @id and other attributes

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. I even tried to create the following xpath but it is also giving an empty array:

response.xpath('//*[@id=" product_data "]//text()').extract()

Comment: you have two issues, there is empty spaces in //*[@id="product_data"]//text()

secondly scrapy doesn't excecute Js, but this website is using js to display products